# Isolate multiple physical networks with DD-WRT (Atheros)

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have an Archer C7 (Atheros). It has two physical wireless network adapters, one each for 2.4 GHz (`ath0`) and 5 GHz (`ath1`).

I share my internet with my neighbor, he uses `ath0` and I use both `ath1` and the wired ports.

I would like to isolate the two networks from each other, they only need to communicate within themselves and with the internet.

I also have `eth0` and `eth1`, but I don't know what the two actually refer to.

How would I properly separate the networks from each other with DD-WRT?

I tried following [this guide](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Separate_LAN_and_WLAN), but I had no internet connection.

The settings I ended up with are:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try this guide:  [Multiple WLANs](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Multiple_WLANs)

Comment: Do you share the same internet connection? How is that connection being setup?

Comment: @xpac It's set up like a standard router right now, nothing fancy. He has `ath0` with his SSID, I have `ath1` with my SSID, I have the wired ports. Both use DHCP. I haven't touched anything advanced in the router except for attempting to set this up (the screenshot in the question), but those changes were reverted.

Comment: Okay, let me put it differently: How shall it be afterwards? If you say you are using the wired ports right now, I assume you have some kind of modem or router from your ISP which is connected to one of the wired ports right now, and your target is to share that internet connection with your neighbor, but without the ability of him accessing anything on your network or the other way round. Is that right so far?

Comment: @xpac Ah, I see what you're asking, sorry. Yes, cable goes from the wall (Comcast) to my modem, then to the router. I want to share this connection, essentially like we have now. We each have our own physical wireless adapter, and I use the wired connection. I want his adapter/network (`ath0`) completely isolated from my network (`ath1` AND wired), but both should still be able to access the internet.

Comment: Okay, some basics first, some time since I did that: ath0 and ath1 correspond to your 2.4 GHz wifi and the 5.0 GHz wifi. If you're splitting them up like this, one of you will be stuck with 2.4 GHz and the other one with 5.0 GHz, which is not what you want. About eth0 and eth1 - eth0 is usually a dedicated, single WAN port on your router, while eth1 means the four LAN ports. DD-WRT can not differentiate between those LAN ports, they're all the same to it. I'll have to figure out how this is done in DD-WRT and will try to give a better answer here later.

Comment: @xpac We're already set up at 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. I only have 5 GHz devices, so I don't have a problem with it this way. I don't know if there's another problem with that, but it's not a problem to me. Thank you, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

what u really want to do is to setup a GUEST network. There r a number of tuts on that topic (DD=WRT Guest network). I didn't follow the guide u used but a quick look didn't mention Guest so I don't know what that really does.
try setting it up as a guest network.